# Search Multiple fields on an MS Access form using a textbox linked to a subform

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to search multiple fields of a subform from an unbound textbox on the main form, but it doesn't seem to be filtering anything. No error messages come up either. My code is:

```
Private Sub btnSearch2_Click()
Dim strfilter As String

If Me.GlobalSearch.Value <> "" Then
Me.FilterOn = False
Me.GlobalSearch.SetFocus
Else
strfilter = "(HarvestId LIKE '*" & Me.GlobalSearch.Value & "*' OR "
strfilter = strfilter & "AssignedTo LIKE '*" & Me.GlobalSearch.Value & "*' OR "
strfilter = strfilter & "HarvestStatus LIKE '*" & Me.GlobalSearch.Value & "*')"
End If
'If strfilter <> "" Then
'Me.Filter = strfilter
'Me.FilterOn = True
'Else
'Me.FilterOn = False
'End If
End Sub
```

Where GlobalSearch is the search textbox and HarvestId, AssignedTo and HarvestStatus the fields I want to search on in the subform. Why isn't the code working?
Thanks
Mari

Comment: Firstly, you realise that the last few lines of your code are commented? You have mentioned that you are attempting to search fields within a *subform*, however since you are using the `Me` keyword from within the event handler for a element presumably on the *parent* form, the filter is being applied to the *parent* form, not the subform.

Comment: Ok, thanks, forgot that I had commented out some of the code. Aside from that, what changes do I need to make to the code then so it search the subform and not the main form? GlobalSearch is the search textbox on the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your subform is called `HarvestSub`, replace your commented code with something like:

```
If strfilter <> "" Then
    Me.HarvestSub.Form.Filter = strfilter
    Me.HarvestSub.Form.FilterOn = True
Else
    Me.HarvestSub.Form.FilterOn = False
End If
```